# NullPointerException при поиске ListView

Tags: android, listview, filter

Здравствуйте! Есть список (ListView), заполненный данными, есть строка поиска (EditText). Список отображается верно, но если ввести любой символ - возникает NullPointerException:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
EditText edit;
ListView lv;
SimpleAdapter aa;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> al;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HashMap<String, Object> hm;
    al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense",
            "HTC Sensation XE", "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800", 
            "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
    String from[] = { "name", "img" };
    int to[] = { R.id.text1, R.id.img };

    for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
    {
        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put("name", products[i]);
        hm.put("img", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        al.add(hm);
    }

    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    aa = new SimpleAdapter(this, al, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            aa.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Title"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

**Логи:**

```
06-21 20:10:35.548: W/Filter(4368): An exception occured during performFiltering()!
06-21 20:10:35.548: W/Filter(4368): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
06-21 20:10:35.548: W/Filter(4368): at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.performFiltering(SimpleAdapter.java:352)
06-21 20:10:35.548: W/Filter(4368): at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
06-21 20:10:35.548: W/Filter(4368): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 20:10:35.548: W/Filter(4368): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 20:10:35.548: W/Filter(4368): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-21 20:10:35.618: D/AndroidRuntime(4368): Shutting down VM
06-21 20:10:35.618: W/dalvikvm(4368): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a611f8)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:700)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:823)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AbsListView.java:5612)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:47)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:59)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(SimpleAdapter.java:383)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-21 20:10:35.628: E/AndroidRuntime(4368): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос на этом сайте: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Он на английском, но ничего сложного там в понимании нет.

Необходимо создать свой адаптер и фильтр (создать класс и унаследовать его от Filter). Могу прикрепить свой проект, где это реализуется (только это, ничего лишнего). Моя проблема заключалась в том, как сказал Saidolim Djuraev.

Comment: Если не сложно, опишите в двух словах решение здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку ищите тут

```
aa.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```

предпочитается не использовать `SimpleAdapter` с фильтром `SimpleFilter` который используется внутри `SimpleAdapter`.

Он имеет баг как все значении должны бить `Strings`

также проверьте что при вводе `EditText1` не очищается ? Может это тоже у Вас проблема.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, на счет этого я в курсе, но как решить эту проблему? делать свой адаптер? заранее спасибо!